# LogIN Website using CURL

Tags: linux, bash, login

Full Topic: I want to automate my ISP login whenever it expires.
For this, first I need to automate the login process to the website and I'm stuck at the very first step.

The source code of the page can be viewed [here](https://pastebin.com/e9YhAx7e).

I tried

- `curl --data "uname=UID&pwd=PWD" p.q.r.s:xxxx/abc/efg/Login.jsp`
- `curl --data "document.login.Username.value=UID&document.login.Password.value=PWD" p.q.r.s:xxxx/abc/efg/Login.jsp`
- `curl --data "theName=UID&theEmail=PWD" p.q.r.s:xxxx/abc/efg/Login.jsp`
- `curl --user UID:PWD p.q.r.s:xxxx/abc/efg/Login.jsp -v`
- `curl --user UID:PWD p.q.r.s:xxxx/abc/efg/Login.jsp`

UID and PWD are userID and password respectively.

Comment: Consider trying [GitHub - broadband-auto-login](https://github.com/uniquerockrz/broadband-auto-login). It includes an automatic logon via cron job.  If it doesn't work, the code might be useful for whatever solution ends up working for you.

Comment: Well this might be interesting. As this open up browser it's my last option to check. However, many thanks for sharing.